# Scrollable Overlay with Fixed Content Underneath

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make the overlay in this example be able to scroll all the way out of the screen. The content needs to be in a fixed position as it is in the example below. How can I allow the overlay div to be scrolled all the way outside of the viewport?

EXAMPLE SITE:
https://www.ssk.com/

HTML

```
<div class="test-overlay"></div>
    <div class="test-content-container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.test-overlay {
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 995;
}

.test-content-container {
    background: rgba(156,64,81,1.00);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding 100% padding to the bottom of a container div containing these two elements.

HTML

```
<div class="test-complete-container">
<div class="test-overlay"></div>
    <div class="test-content-container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test-overlay {
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 995;
}

.test-content-container {
    background: rgba(156,64,81,1.00);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
    .test-complete-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
```